# Where is $(CudaToolkitBinDir) defined in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda

I just installed cuda 6.5 on my computer alongside 5.0 and 5.5, which was working fine. However, the variable/macro $(CudaToolkitBinDir) still points to the 5.5 path. $(CUDA_PATH) is correctly defined as the 6.5 path as well as are all variables that extend it (INC_PATH etc.). The family of macros that aren't capitalized (CudaToolkit____) are still set to 5.5.

I've checked:

1. the system (Windows 7) environment variables (has the CUDA_PATH family)
2. the user Property Pages -> User Macros
3. the Nsight options

Googleing CudaToolkitBinDir didn't turn up anything. I've reinstalled cuda 6.5 to no avail.

Where is the definition located or how can I reset it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was as follows:

Right click on the project. Select Build Customizations... Select the correct Cuda version.

D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

Check the registry to see if there is a key named `InstallDir` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5`.

If it does not exist, increase it and its value is the installation path of CUDA. like this: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5`.

Remarks: replace `v11.5` with your CUDA version